# optimization of updating only missing values in the master dataset via update statement

Tags: sas

I have a master dataset that contains missing values.

Sample looks like

```
Date    Index1    Index2  Key
01NOV    20          .    a
02NOV     .         30    a
02NOV    10         20    a
```

I also have a update dataset that contains no missing values.

```
Date    Index1    Index2  Key
01NOV    10         10    a
02NOV     5         40    a
```

The idea is, if data matches and master dataset has missing values under `index` then replace it with corresponding `index` in the `update` dataset. If not, preserve its value.

Output should be

```
Date    Index1    Index2  Key
01NOV    20         10    a
01NOV     5         30    a
02NOV    10         20    a
```

My code is below

```
proc sql;
update master as a
set index1 = case when a.index1 ^= . then a.index1 else (select index1 from update as b where a.Date = b.Date and a.Key = b.Key) end,
index2 = case when a.index2 ^= . then a.index2 else (select index2 from update as b where a.Date = b.Date and a.Key = b.Key) end;
quit;
```

But both `master` and `update` are large. Is there a way to optimize this?

**EDIT**

How to update the `master` within a specific period? `where a.Date = b.Date and a.Date between sDate and eDate`?

Comment: How large are we talking about?

Comment: 150M in `master` and 10M in `update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SQL Update is too slow, then the best way to do this is probably to create formats or a hash table, depending on your available memory and how many variables you have. SQL `update` will tend to be slow in cases like this, even if you have properly indexed tables.

It's probably worth giving it a try first with the SQL Update, though, with properly indexed tables.

1. Make sure all tables are sorted by date.
2. Create indexes on both tables on `date`.
3. Update one at a time.

This example is pretty quick for me - 4 minutes or so for 6.5MM/1.5MM rows where about half of the 6.5MM rows need updating - obviously 150MM rows will take longer, but the total time should scale well.

```
data sample;
  call streaminit(7);
  do key = 1 to 1000;
      do date = '01JAN2011'd to '31DEC2014'd;
        do _t = 1 to rand('Normal',5,2);
          if rand('Uniform') < 0.8 then val1=10;
          if rand('Uniform') < 0.6 then val2=20;
          output;
          call missing(of val1, val2);
        end;
      end;
  end;
run;

data update_t;
  do key = 1 to 1000;
      do date='01JAN2011'd to '31DEC2014'd;
        val1=10;
        val2=20;
        output;
      end;
  end;
run;


proc sql;
  create index keydate on sample (key, date);
  create index keydate on update_t  (key, date);

  update sample S
    set val1=coalesce(val1,
        (select val1 from update_t U where U.key = S.key and U.date=S.date)),
        val2=coalesce(val2,
        (select val2 from update_t U where U.key = S.key and U.date=S.date))
    where n(s.val1,s.val2) < 2;
quit;
```

I make sure that only rows with a missing val get updated with the `where` statement, but otherwise this is pretty standard.  Unfortunately SAS won't do updates with joins (it may well work the same on the back end, but you can't say `update S,U set S.blah=U.blah` as you can in some other SQLs).  Note here the SAMPLE and UPDATE tables are both sorted (because I created them sorted); if they weren't sorted you would need to sort both of them to get optimal behavior.

If you want a faster option, a format or hash table is your friend.  I'll show the format here.

```
data update_formats;
  set update_t;
  length start $50;
  start=catx('|',key,date);
  label=val1;
  fmtname='$VAL1F';
  output;
  label=val2;
  fmtname='$VAL2F';
  output;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    hlo='o';
    label=' ';
    start=' ';
    output;
    fmtname='$VAL1F';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=update_formats;
by fmtname;
run;

proc format cntlin=update_formats;
quit;

data sample;
  modify sample;
  if n(val1,val2) < 2;  *where is slower for some reason;
  val1=coalesce(val1,input(put(catx('|',key,date),$VAL1F.),best12.));
  val2=coalesce(val2,input(put(catx('|',key,date),$VAL2F.),best12.));
run;
```

This uses formats to convert id+date to val1 or val2.  It will tend to be faster than the SQL `update` unless the number of rows in the update table is very high (1.5MM should be okay, eventually though format starts to slow down).  The total time for this will tend to be not much higher than the write time for the table - in this case (baseline: 2 seconds to write SAMPLE initially) it took 13 seconds to load the formats and then another 13 seconds to use them/write the new SAMPLE dataset - total time under 30 seconds versus 4 minutes for the SQL update (and also not requiring index creation or sorting the bigger table).